# How to assign an object to an inhereted function

Tags: c++, file, inheritance, methods

how can I assign an inherited method to an object?
, can you explain to me what is wrong with my code?
I am a newbie, so I would like to know if there is a better way to do it

```
int main(){
    CalculateData data;
    data = data.ReadData(data);//does not let me assign data to the method??
}
```

Rest of the code

```
#include<string>#include<fstream>#include<iostream>#include<vector>using namespace std;

class File//base class
{
private:
    double Size;
public:
    vector <double>values;

    double GetSize();
    void SetSize(double size);

    File ReadData(File data);
};


class CalculateData :public File {//inherent from file class
    
public:
    std::vector <double> value;

}

File  File::ReadData(File file) {//method of File class

    {std::fstream File("Data.txt", std::ios_base::in);
double a;
int counter = 0;

    while (File >> a)
    {
        //printf("%f ", a);
        file.values.push_back(a);
        counter++;
    }
    file.SetSize(counter);
    cout << "size is " << file.GetSize() << endl;

    File.close();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: you are not assigning the method, but you are trying to assign the returned value to `data` but they are different types. Please post the compiler error message.

Comment: error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'File' (or there is no acceptable conversion).                                                             note: could be 'CalculateData &CalculateData::operator =(const CalculateData &)'
 note: while trying to match the argument list '(CalculateData, File)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, it is hard to help, because the error is just a consequence of a flawed approach. I'll use an example simpler than yours that has most of the same issues:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int value;
    Base read(Base b) {
        b.value = 42;
        return b;
    };
};

struct Derived : Base{
    int values;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d = d.read(d);
}
```

The immediate problem is the compiler error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:17: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Derived' and 'Base')
   17 |     d = d.read(d);
      |                 ^
<source>:11:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived&)'
   11 | struct Derived : Base{
      |        ^~~~~~~
<source>:11:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Base' to 'const Derived&'
<source>:11:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr Derived& Derived::operator=(Derived&&)'
<source>:11:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Base' to 'Derived&&'
```

`d` is a `Derived` and `read` returns a `Base`. They are different types, you cannot assign them to each other unless you provide some conversion between them.

However, it does not make sense that `read` takes a `Base` as argument (by value) and returns that just to let the caller assign it to the object they called the method on. If the method is intended to modify the current object then it should do so directly:

```
 void read() {
     value = 42;
 }
```

There is absolutely no need to pass a `Base` as argument, which will be copied anyhow, because you pass it by value.

The next thing that is fishy in the code is that `Derived` has another member which is similar named as the one of `Base` but unused. `Derived` already does inherit the `value` member from `Base`. It does not need another `values` member.

Last but not least, initialization of members should take place in the initializer list of the constructor (if not in-class initializers are used). If initialization is complicated a `static` method can be used. Hence:

```
struct Base {
    int value;
    Base() : value( read_input() ) {}
   
    static int read_input() {
         return 42;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {};

int main() {
   Derived d;
}
```

This code does the same as the above. As it is not clear what the purpose of `Derived` is, it can be removed.